# How to use socket in Java

Tags: c#, java, sockets

I am having some trouble using sockets in Java. I am creating an application that continually needs to send the data to a server. The data is sent through the socket from client. I am using following code:

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

while(send)
{
    soc=new Socket(serverAddr,8210);
    outStream=soc.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(data);
    outStream.close();
}
```

The above code is working fine and there is no issue with this.
Here I am creating a new object of `Socket` in every loop and I think this is not a good implementation method. How can I send the data to server using one `Socket`? (I don't want to create a new object in every loop)

And here is the code of server that I had written in C#:

```
while (true)
{
    Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(s);
    int d;
    while ((d = ns.ReadByte()) >= 0)
    {
        //Process data here
    }
    s.Close();
}
```

Also what modification I need to do in server side?

Thanks

Comment: There are some fundamental differences between sending multiple messages on a single stream, and sending 1 message each on multiple streams; in particular, your "Process data here" needs to be able to correctly distinguish different messages. You probably already have this covered...  I'm just mentioning it to be thorough

Comment: @Marc, messages are seperate in this case because he open a new socket per message. very inefficient however it does break up messages ;)

Comment: @Peter - exactly; if he switches to one socket, that changes. Depending on the message format, that *might* be fine, or it *might* need tweaking - for example a length-prefix per message

Comment: If I control both server and client I usually prefer doing things through HTTP connections. There is a bit more overhead but I save implementing all the protocol stuff.

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments and guidelines. I just figured out what to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that creating a new socket object will also create a new TCP connection. If you want to use a single connection, preserve the output stream. You'll need to consider cleanup on exceptions, and you may also need a further layer around this for recovery if there is a transient network failure in between.

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);


soc=new Socket(serverAddr,8210);
try {
    outStream=soc.getOutputStream();
    while(send)
    {
        outStream.write(data);
    } 
    outStream.close();
} finally {
    soc.close();
}
```

For the server side: your code is basically correct, but you also need to consider cleanup (use `using`), and as Marc Gravell points out, you need to be sure you can find the message boundaries when you are using a single TCP connection.